# How to use "A comparison of" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, comparison

I am writing a scientific paper and I need to use "A comparison of..." as title of a table that illustrates both results.

**First experiment:** I used the best 200 features.

**Second experiment:** I used the whole features 500 features.

Which sentence is correct?

1) A comparison of recognition results, where fall is simulated, using **either** the best 100 features **or** the whole (376) features.

*or*

2) A comparison of recognition results, where fall is simulated, using the best 100 features and the whole (376) features.
Any suggestion?

Comment: A _comparison_ is made _**between**_ comparands.

Comment: Instead of "the whole features" I would use "all of the features".

Comment: @user3169 both sentences are correct?

Comment: You might consider using the word _between_, e.g.: _"Comparison between results of experiments using A. The best 200 features, and B. All 500 features"_, or similar. Both of your sentences are "correct", but neither is an accurate description.

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

> A comparison of recognition results, where fall is simulated, **between** the best 100 features and **all 376** features.

*between* is better when comparing items.

You can't use *comparison* (involving at least 2 items) with *either* (involving only one item at a time). It becomes a comparison of one thing.

2) is not technically wrong, but *using* is vague in this context.

Comment: You might also consider removing the comma after results. As I read the statement it doesn't seem necessary.